# Remove all items from an array NOT in array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections, synchronization, mongodb-query

I have two collections in Mongo. For simplification I´m providing a minified example

**Template Collection:**

```
{
   templateId:0,
   values:[
      {data:"a"},
      {data:"b"},
      {data:"c"}
      {data:"e"}
   ]
}
```

**Data Collection:**

```
{
   dataId:0,
   templateId:0,
   values:[
      {data:"a",
      value: 10},
      {data:"b",
      value: 120},
      {data:"c",
      value: 3220},
      {data:"d",
      value: 0}
   ]
}
```

I want to make a sync from **Template Collection -> Data Collection**, between the template 0 and all documents using that template. In the case of the example, that would mean:

1. Copy {data:"e"} into the arrays of all documents with the templateId: 0
2. Remove {data:"d"} from the arrays of all documents with the templateId: 0
3. BUT do not touch the rest of the items. I can´t simply replace the array, because those values have to be kept

**I´ve found a solution for 1.**

db.getCollection('data').update({templateId:0},
         {$addToSet: {values: {
            $each:[ 
               {data:"a"},
               {data:"b"},
               {data:"c"}
               {data:"e"} 
            ]
            }}}, {
                multi: true}
                )

**And a partial solution for 2.**

I got it. First tried with $pullAll, but the normal $pull seems to work together with the $nin operator

```
db.getCollection('data').update({templateId:"QNXC4bPAF9J6r9FQu"},
         {$pull:{values: { $nin:[ 
             {data:"a"},
             {data:"b"},
             {data:"c"}
             {data:"e"}]
            }}}, {
                multi: true}
                )
```

This will remove **{data:"d"}** from all document arrays, but it seems to **overwrite** the complete array, and this is not what I want, as those **value** entries need to be persisted

But how can I perform a query like **Remove everything from an array EXCEPT/NOT IN [a,b,c,d,...]** ?

Comment: why don't you replace the data array by the template array ? Otherwise you can have a look at [**$setIntersection**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator

Comment: @felix I can´t do that. It´s a simplified example. In the real case I have additional data in {data:"e",value:1,value:2,...} which I can´t replace. I only want to touch those items which are either new, or not used anymore. setIntersection won´t work here because of that. template instances are unique and can´t be overwritten:(